How to check if 2 Cards can have the same heights in Compose?
I have list of pairs for title and description.
Need to put each pair in Texts one under another, then to the Card and then try to put 2 of them to the Row.
If 2 Cards in Row can have the same height - then they should be in one Row, if not - then go to separate Rows.
Some limitations:

Text with title should be 1 line max
no ellipsise
width of Cards can be different

